# Scroll to table row when table is created dynamically

Tags: jquery

I got a table, which I am populating within,

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
     PopulateMyTable(); 
     // here scroll to the right row
     // 1015 is a dynamic generated id of row.

     $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("tr[data-id=" + 1015 + "]").offset().top
    }, 2000);       
});
```

Now problem is, when I use debugger, even though code passed through `PopulateMyTable` method, but it didn't populated the table in HTML as if i look in developer tools as a result i get this error,

**Exception**

`can't use top function on undefined`

I am adding rows dynamically

```
// get data from rest API and  it

function PopulateMyTable() 
{
       $("#MyTable").append("<tr data-id='" + ID +"' onclick='DoSomething(" + ID + ")'>"); 
}
```

Comment: What's the `ID` in `PopulateMyTable()`? Where is it defined?

Comment: @P5Coder please read the comment, it's getting from rest Api :-)

Comment: Looks like the row(s) are not in the DOM yet when you call $("tr[data-id=" + 1015 + "]")